# Custom View Engine not finding a view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, partial-views, viewengine

I've successfully created a custom view engine and able to browse custom views that are found in different location other than the default. eg`/Views/Module1/Controller/ViewName`
Since my custom view engine overrides the default view route, it is unable to open views that are found in default location. (`/View/Controller/ViewName`).
At this time I modified my custom view engine to refer the default location also. But I ended up getting this kind of error

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The view 'Login' was not found. The following locations were searched:
> /Account/Login.cshtml
> /Shared/Login.cshtml'
> /Module1/Account/Login
> ```

`Login.cshtml` is really found in `/Account/Login.cshtml` but it is not getting it even if it says that it searched on that directory.
my custom view engine looks like this

```
    public class LibraryViewEngine : IViewLocationExpander
    {
        public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
        {
            yield return "/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
            yield return "/Module1/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
            yield return "/Module1/Shared/{0}.cshtml";
            yield return "/Shared/{0}.cshtml";
        }

        public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context)
        {
        }
    }
```

and added the reference on startup

```
  services.Configure<RazorViewEngineOptions>(o =>
            {
                o.ViewLocationExpanders.Add(new LibraryViewEngine());
            });
```

My problem is the same with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070177/razor-engine-not-finding-views) question but we're using different version and we're using different way of implementing custom view engine.
My .net versin is ASP.NET CORE (5.0) and I am using IViewLocationExpander to implement custom view engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you pld try codes below?

```
yield return "Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml";
yield return "Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml";
```

I also did a test in my side with your code, and I faced the same error. So I tried to change my controller to `return View("Views/Hello/Index.cshtml")` instead of the default `return View()`, then I found the issue became `can't find _layout.cshtml`, so I'm afraid the issue should relate to `ExpandViewLocations`. And after adding `Views` before the route string, my code worked again.

Comment: Thanks. I've figured it out finally. by adding `Views/ ` it works correctly. Thanks for the help.